# Using Ticks in actionPerformed - How to display image for 5 seconds

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I'm trying to display an image (iconLabel4) for 5 seconds and then display another image (imageLabel) on top of it after. Why doesn't the code work as intended?

When I run it, what happens is this: I press the button "Bathe" and nothing happens.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

**Code:**

```
JButton bathe = new JButton("Bathe");
bathe.setBounds(370, 450, 80, 25);

bathe.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

                String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();

                if (SHOW_ACTION.equals(actionCommand)){
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 5000) {
                        iconLabel4.setVisible(true);
                    } }
                iconLabel4.setVisible(false);
                imageLabel.setVisible(true);

                repaint();
            };
        });
bathe.setActionCommand(SHOW_ACTION);
panel.add(bathe);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use a `while` loop for timing. Use a `javax.swing.Timer`. See more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Here's the basic construct

   ```
   Timer (int delayInMillis, ActionListener listener)
   ```

   where `delayInMillis` is the millisecond delay between "ticks". Every tick will fire an `ActionEvent`, just like a button press would. So the listener you pass to the timer, had the `actionPerformed` method that will be called every tick.
2. Just use *one* `JLabel` and two `ImageIcons`. When you try to set component visible and not visible after the containter is already visible, you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container. That's not the correct approach though. Just use *one* label, and make use of the method `JLabel.setIcon(ImageIcon)` when you want to change the icon.
3. Don't use null layouts. Learn to use layout managers and let them do the positioning for you. See more at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Huh.. I had to up vote based on a quick glance that included point 3, but then I noticed your artful inclusion of code (formatting) in a list.  That is something I always have trouble with.  Nice work!

Comment: @AndrewThompson 8 spaces instead of 4 :-). Oh and to continue the paragraph point after the code, just go to next line, don't skip a line :-)

Comment: *"8 spaces instead of 4"*  Aha!  *"(after) don't skip a line* Got it.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you ***can*** use `Thread.sleep(5000)`.

***Considerations:*** *Thread.sleep() is inaccurate. How inaccurate depends on the underlying operating system and its timers and schedulers. I've experienced that garbage collection going on in parallel can lead to excessive sleep.* - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737109/4286300)

But if you don't mind a few milliseconds here and there, its easier.