# Java - Why does this basic ticking class use up so much cpu?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu

**Details:**
For a lot the programs that I develop I use this code (or some slight variant) to "tick" a method every so often, set to the varaible tps (if set to 32 it calls the method tick 32 times every second). Its very essential so I can't remove it from my code as animations and various other parts will break.

Unfortunately it seems to use a sizable amount of cpu usage for a reason I can't figure out. A while back I was thinking about using thread.sleep() to fix this issue but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736681/how-accurate-is-thread-sleep); it's rather innacurate which makes it unfeasible as this requires reasonably accurate timing.

It doesn't use that much cpu, around 6-11% cpu for a ryzen 1700 in my admittedly short testing, but it's still quite a lot considering how little it's doing. Is there a less cpu intensive method of completing this? Or will the timing be to innacurate for regular usage.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public ThreadTest() {
        int tps = 32;

        boolean threadShouldRun = true;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double ns = 1000000000 / tps;
        double delta = 0;
        long now;

        while (threadShouldRun) {
            now = System.nanoTime();

            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            while ((delta >= 1) && (threadShouldRun)) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest();
    }
}
```

**Basic summary:** The code above uses 6-11% cpu with a ryzen 1700, is there a way in java to accomplish the same code with less cpu usage and keeping reasonable timing when executing code a certain amount of times per second.

Comment: How many time tick method is executing (can you add a counter and print it?)

When are you updating threadShouldRun? 

My suggestion is to print nanoseconds after each statement and see where the delay is.

Comment: Because the thread is constantly running with no sleep or voluntary yield. While the intention is to provide a hight level of precision, it will tend to run the thread hot (and continuously consume CPU cycles)

Comment: A single-threaded infinite loop consumes one core, what more/less could you want ? ;)

Comment: The threadShouldRun method is for stopping the program, so it doesnt run indefinitely, normaly it will change, but in the short code I made for the question it doesnt.

Comment: This is a solved problem and you should consider using a scheduling service as suggested. But even without doing that, you'll probably notice some improvement with minimal risk of inaccuracy simply by adding `Thread.yield()` in your tight loop.

Comment: @PaulHicks With Java 9, you can now use `Thread.onSpinWait();` as well.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Seems like `onSpinWait()` is specifically for cases where something else needs to happen, so in this case, `yield()` might be the more self-documenting option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy alternative that shouldn't use as much CPU is to use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

    }, 0, 31250, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
}
```

Note that `31250` represents the value of `1/32` seconds converted to microseconds, as that parameter accepts a `long`.