# marquee (ticker,text scroll) with java2d or javafx stutters

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, java-2d, vsync

I'm trying to write a smooth ticker (text running from rigth to left on the screen).
It is almost as I want it, but there are still some stutters. I would like it to be as smooth as cloud moving in the sky. 30 years ago I managed with a few lines of assembler code, but in Java I fail.

It get's worse if I increase the speed (number of pixels I move the text at once).

Is there some kind of synchronization to the screen refresh missing?

**EDIT**

I updated my code according to @camickr remark to launch the window in an exclusive fullscreen windows, which lead to a sligth improvement.
Other things I tried:

- Added ExtendedBufferCapabilities which is supposed to consider vsync
- Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
- enabled opengl
- tried a gaming loop
- added some debugging info

When I use 30 fps and move the text only one pixel, on a 4k display it looks quite good but is also very slow. As soon as I increase to speed to 2 pixels it's starts to stutter.

I'm starting to think that it is simply not possible to achieve my goal with java2d and I have to move to some opengl-library.

Here is my code:

```
package scrolling;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.ImageCapabilities;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import sun.java2d.pipe.hw.ExtendedBufferCapabilities;

/**
 * A smooth scroll with green background to be used with a video cutter.
 * 
 * sun.java2d.pipe.hw.ExtendedBufferCapabilities is restricted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l
 * 
 */
public class MyScroll extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private int targetFps = 30;
    private boolean isOpenGl = false;
    private boolean isVsync = true;
    private boolean useGamingLoop = false;
    private int speed = 1;
    private String message;

    private int fontSize = 120;
    private Font theFont;
    private transient int leftEdge; // Offset from window's right edge to left edge
    private Color bgColor;
    private Color fgColor;
    private int winWidth;
    private int winHeight;
    private double position = 0.77;
    private FontMetrics fontMetrics;
    private int yPositionScroll;
    private boolean isFullScreen;
    private long lastTimerStart = 0;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private Graphics2D graphicsScroll;
    private GraphicsDevice currentScreenDevice = null;
    private int msgWidth = 0;
    private Timer scrollTimer;
    private boolean isRunning;

    /* gaming loop variables */
    private static final long NANO_IN_MILLI = 1000000L;
    // num of iterations with a sleep delay of 0ms before
    // game loop yields to other threads.
    private static final int NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD = 16;
    // max num of renderings that can be skipped in one game loop,
    // game's internal state is updated but not rendered on screen.
    private static int MAX_RENDER_SKIPS = 5;
    // private long prevStatsTime;
    private long gameStartTime;
    private long curRenderTime;
    private long rendersSkipped = 0L;
    private long period; // period between rendering in nanosecs
    private long fps;
    private long frameCounter;
    private long lastFpsTime;

    public void init() {
        fontSize = getWidth() / 17;

        if (getGraphicsConfiguration().getBufferCapabilities().isPageFlipping()) {    
            try { // no pageflipping available with opengl
                BufferCapabilities cap = new BufferCapabilities(new ImageCapabilities(true), new ImageCapabilities(true), BufferCapabilities.FlipContents.BACKGROUND);
                // ExtendedBufferCapabilities is supposed to do a vsync
                ExtendedBufferCapabilities ebc = new ExtendedBufferCapabilities(cap, ExtendedBufferCapabilities.VSyncType.VSYNC_ON);
                createBufferStrategy(2, ebc);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
        }

        System.out.println(getDeviceConfigurationString(getGraphicsConfiguration()));

        message = "This is a test.   ";
        leftEdge = 0;
        theFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        bgColor = getBackground();
        fgColor = getForeground();
        winWidth = getSize().width - 1;
        winHeight = getSize().height;
        yPositionScroll = (int) (winHeight * position);

        initScrollImage();
    }

    /**
     * Draw the entire text to a buffered image to copy it to the screen later.
     */
    private void initScrollImage() {
        Graphics2D og = (Graphics2D) getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
        fontMetrics = og.getFontMetrics(theFont);
        Rectangle2D rect = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(message, og);
        img = new BufferedImage((int) rect.getWidth(), (int) rect.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // At each frame, we get a reference on the rendering buffer graphics2d.
        // To handle concurrency, we 'cut' it into graphics context for each cube.
        graphicsScroll = img.createGraphics();
        graphicsScroll.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphicsScroll.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        graphicsScroll.setFont(theFont);
        graphicsScroll.setColor(bgColor);
        graphicsScroll.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()); // clear offScreen Image.
        graphicsScroll.setColor(fgColor);
        msgWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(message);

        graphicsScroll.setColor(Color.white);
        graphicsScroll.drawString(message, 1, img.getHeight() - 10);

        // for better readability in front of an image draw an outline arround the text
        graphicsScroll.setColor(Color.black);
        graphicsScroll.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        graphicsScroll.translate(1, img.getHeight() - 10);
        FontRenderContext frc = graphicsScroll.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, message);
        graphicsScroll.draw(gv.getOutline());
    }

    public void start() {
        scrollTimer = new Timer(1000 / targetFps, this);
        scrollTimer.setRepeats(true);
        scrollTimer.setCoalesce(true);
        scrollTimer.start();        
    }

    public void startGamingloop() {
        // loop initialization
        long beforeTime, afterTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;
        long overSleepTime = 0L;
        int noDelays = 0;
        long excess = 0L;
        gameStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        // prevStatsTime = gameStartTime;
        beforeTime = gameStartTime;

        period = (1000L * NANO_IN_MILLI) / targetFps; // rendering FPS (nanosecs/targetFPS)
        System.out.println("FPS: " + targetFps + ", vsync=");
        System.out.println("FPS period: " + period);

        // gaming loop http://www.javagaming.org/index.php/topic,19971.0.html
        while (true) {
            // **2) execute physics
            updateLeftEdge();

            // **1) execute drawing
            drawScroll();

            // Synchronise with the display hardware.
            // Flip the buffer
            if (!getBufferStrategy().contentsLost()) {
                getBufferStrategy().show();
            }
            if (isVsync) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            }

            afterTime = System.nanoTime();
            curRenderTime = afterTime;
            calculateFramesPerSecond();

            timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTime;
            if (sleepTime > 0) { // time left in cycle
                // System.out.println("sleepTime: " + (sleepTime/NANO_IN_MILLI));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime / NANO_IN_MILLI);// nano->ms
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                overSleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - afterTime) - sleepTime;
            } else { // sleepTime <= 0;
                System.out.println("Rendering too slow");
                // this cycle took longer than period
                excess -= sleepTime;
                // store excess time value
                overSleepTime = 0L;
                if (++noDelays >= NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD) {
                    Thread.yield();
                    // give another thread a chance to run
                    noDelays = 0;
                }
            }

            beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

            /*
             * If the rendering is taking too long, then update the game state without rendering it, to get the UPS nearer to the required frame rate.
             */
            int skips = 0;
            while ((excess > period) && (skips < MAX_RENDER_SKIPS)) {
                // update state but don’t render
                System.out.println("Skip renderFPS, run updateFPS");
                excess -= period;
                updateLeftEdge();
                skips++;
            }
            rendersSkipped += skips;
        }
    }

    private void calculateFramesPerSecond() {
        if (curRenderTime - lastFpsTime >= NANO_IN_MILLI * 1000) {
            fps = frameCounter;
            frameCounter = 0;
            lastFpsTime = curRenderTime;
        }
        frameCounter++;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        render();
    }

    private void render() {
        if (!isFullScreen) {
            repaint(0, yPositionScroll, winWidth, yPositionScroll + fontMetrics.getAscent());
        } else {
            getBufferStrategy().show();
        }
        if (isVsync) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        }
        updateLeftEdge();
        drawScroll();
    }

    /**
     * Draws (part) of the prerendered image with text to a position in the screen defined by an increasing 
     * variable "leftEdge".
     * 
     * @return time drawing took. 
     */
    private long drawScroll() {
        long beforeDrawText = System.nanoTime();

        if (winWidth - leftEdge + msgWidth < 0) { // Current scroll entirely off-screen.
            leftEdge = 0;
        }
        int x = winWidth - leftEdge;
        int sourceWidth = Math.min(leftEdge, img.getWidth());
        Graphics2D og = (Graphics2D) getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
        try { // copy the pre drawn scroll to the screen
            og.drawImage(img.getSubimage(0, 0, sourceWidth, img.getHeight()), x, yPositionScroll, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " " + x + " " + sourceWidth);
        }
        long afterDrawText = System.nanoTime();
        return afterDrawText - beforeDrawText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyScroll scroll = new MyScroll();

        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", String.valueOf(scroll.isOpenGl())); // enable opengl
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.renderer.verbose", "true");
        String renderer = "undefined";
        try {
            renderer = sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine.getInstance().getClass().getName();
            System.out.println("Renderer " + renderer);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            // may fail with JDK9 jigsaw (jake)
            if (false) {
                System.err.println("Unable to get RenderingEngine.getInstance()");
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        scroll.setBackground(Color.green);
        scroll.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] screens = env.getScreenDevices();
        // I want the external monitor attached to my notebook
        GraphicsDevice device = screens[screens.length - 1]; 
        boolean isFullScreenSupported = device.isFullScreenSupported();

        scroll.setFullScreen(isFullScreenSupported);
        scroll.setUndecorated(isFullScreenSupported);
        scroll.setResizable(!isFullScreenSupported);

        if (isFullScreenSupported) {
            device.setFullScreenWindow(scroll);
            scroll.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
            scroll.validate();
        } else {
            // Windowed mode
            Rectangle r = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
            scroll.setSize(r.width, r.height);
            scroll.pack();
            scroll.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            scroll.setVisible(true);
        }

        // exit on pressing escape
        scroll.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    scroll.setRunning(false);
                    if(scroll.getScrollTimer() != null) {
                        scroll.getScrollTimer().stop();
                    }
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        scroll.setVisible(true);
        scroll.init();
        if (scroll.isUseGamingLoop()) {
            scroll.startGamingloop();
        } else {
            scroll.start();
        }

    }

    private void updateLeftEdge() {
        leftEdge += speed;
    }

    public Timer getScrollTimer() {
        return scrollTimer;
    }

    public void setFullScreen(boolean isFullScreen) {
        this.isFullScreen = isFullScreen;
    }

    public void setTargetFps(int targetFps) {
        this.targetFps = targetFps;
    }

    public void setOpenGl(boolean isOpenGl) {
        this.isOpenGl = isOpenGl;
    }

    public void setVsync(boolean isVsync) {
        this.isVsync = isVsync;
    }

    public void setUseGamingLoop(boolean useGamingLoop) {
        this.useGamingLoop = useGamingLoop;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    private String getDeviceConfigurationString(GraphicsConfiguration gc){
        return "Bounds: " + gc.getBounds() + "\n" + 
                "Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "   Back Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" + 
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getBackBufferCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n" +
                "   Flip Contents: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFlipContents() + "\n" +
                "   Front Buffer Capabilities: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities() + "\n" +
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" +
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().getFrontBufferCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n" +
                "   Is Full Screen Required: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isFullScreenRequired() + "\n" +
                "   Is MultiBuffer Available: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isMultiBufferAvailable() + "\n" +
                "   Is Page Flipping: " + gc.getBufferCapabilities().isPageFlipping() + "\n" +
                "Device: " + gc.getDevice() + "\n" +
                "   Available Accelerated Memory: " + gc.getDevice().getAvailableAcceleratedMemory() + "\n" +
                "   ID String: " + gc.getDevice().getIDstring() + "\n" +
                "   Type: " + gc.getDevice().getType() + "\n" +
                "   Display Mode: " + gc.getDevice().getDisplayMode() + "\n" +              
                "Image Capabilities: " + gc.getImageCapabilities() + "\n" + 
                "      Accelerated: " + gc.getImageCapabilities().isAccelerated() + "\n" + 
                "      True Volatile: " + gc.getImageCapabilities().isTrueVolatile() + "\n";        
    }

    public boolean isOpenGl() {
        return isOpenGl;
    }

    public boolean isUseGamingLoop() {
        return useGamingLoop;
    }    
}
```

Output of graphics capabilities:

```
Renderer sun.java2d.pisces.PiscesRenderingEngine
Bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=3839,y=0,width=3840,height=2160]
Buffer Capabilities: sun.awt.X11GraphicsConfig$XDBECapabilities@68de145
   Back Buffer Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@27fa135a
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
   Flip Contents: undefined
   Front Buffer Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@27fa135a
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
   Is Full Screen Required: false
   Is MultiBuffer Available: false
   Is Page Flipping: true
Device: X11GraphicsDevice[screen=1]
   Available Accelerated Memory: -1
   ID String: :0.1
   Type: 0
   Display Mode: java.awt.DisplayMode@1769
Image Capabilities: java.awt.ImageCapabilities@27fa135a
      Accelerated: false
      True Volatile: false
```

**EDIT 2:**
I wrote the same in javafx now, same result, it is stuttering as soon as I move more than 3 pixels at once.

*I'm running on an Intel i9 9900K, Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile, Ubuntu, OpenJdk 14.*

```
    package scrolling;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * A smooth scroll with green background to be used with a video cutter.
 * 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk
 * 
 */
public class MyScroll extends Application {

    private boolean useGamingLoop = false;
    private int speed = 3;
    private String message;

    private transient double leftEdge; // Offset from window's right edge to left edge
    private Color bgColor;
    private Color fgColor;
    private double winWidth;
    private int winHeight;
    private double position = 0.77;
    private int yPositionScroll;
    private Image img;
    private int msgWidth = 0;
    private Timer scrollTimer;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private ImageView imageView;
    long lastUpdateTime;
    long lastIntervall;
    long nextIntervall;
    String ADAPTIVE_PULSE_PROP = "com.sun.scenario.animation.adaptivepulse";

    int frame = 0;
    long timeOfLastFrameSwitch = 0; 
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        message = "This is a test.   ";
        leftEdge = 0;
        bgColor = Color.green;
        fgColor = Color.white;
        winWidth = (int)Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
        winHeight = (int)Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();
        yPositionScroll = (int) (winHeight * position);

        initScrollImage(stage);

        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);


        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                 nextIntervall = now - lastUpdateTime;
                 System.out.println(lastIntervall - nextIntervall);
                 lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
                 drawScroll(stage);
                 lastIntervall = nextIntervall;
            }
        }.start();

        //Creating a Group object  
        Group root = new Group(imageView);  
        //Creating a scene object 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);  
        //Adding scene to the stage 
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);        
    }


    /**
     * Draw the entire text to an imageview and add to the scene.
     */
    private void initScrollImage(Stage stage) {
        int fontSize = (int)winWidth / 17;

        Font theFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        BufferedImage tempImg = new BufferedImage((int)winWidth, winHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = tempImg.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(theFont);
        Rectangle2D rect = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(message, tempImg.getGraphics());
        msgWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(message);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage((int) rect.getWidth(), (int) rect.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D graphicsScroll = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        graphicsScroll.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphicsScroll.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        graphicsScroll.setFont(theFont);
        graphicsScroll.setColor(bgColor);
        graphicsScroll.fillRect(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight()); // set background color
        graphicsScroll.setColor(fgColor);
        graphicsScroll.drawString(message, 1, bufferedImage.getHeight() - 10);

        // for better readability in front of an image draw an outline arround the text
        graphicsScroll.setColor(Color.black);
        graphicsScroll.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        graphicsScroll.translate(1, bufferedImage.getHeight() - 10);
        FontRenderContext frc = graphicsScroll.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, message);
        graphicsScroll.draw(gv.getOutline());

        img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);

        imageView = new ImageView(img); 
        imageView.setSmooth(false);
        imageView.setCache(true);

        //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view 
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);  

        tempImg.flush();
    }


    /**
     * Draws (part) of the prerendered image with text to a position in the screen defined by an increasing 
     * variable "leftEdge".
     * 
     * @return time drawing took. 
     */
    private void drawScroll(Stage stage) {
        leftEdge += speed;
        if (winWidth - leftEdge + msgWidth < 0) { // Current scroll entirely off-screen.
            leftEdge = 0;
        }
//        imageView.relocate(winWidth - leftEdge, yPositionScroll);
        imageView.setX(winWidth - leftEdge);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        System.setProperty("prism.vsync", "true");
//      System.setProperty("com.sun.scenario.animation.adaptivepulse", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.scenario.animation.vsync", "true");

        launch(args);
    }

    public Timer getScrollTimer() {
        return scrollTimer;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isUseGamingLoop() {
        return useGamingLoop;
    }


    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think that might be the best you can do in a windowed environment. You may have more control when using Full-Screen Exclusive Mode. See [Active Rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)  for more information on this topic.

Comment: I've written a marquee Swing application.  It seems to run fine on Windows 10.  I think Java Swing and possibly JavaFX have painting problems on Unix systems.

Comment: Did you try to use Transition instead of AnimationTimer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running this with Windows 10.  I don't think it will work well on a Unix system.

[image: Marquee GUI 1]

...

[image: Marquee GUI 2]

The code consists of 9 classes in 5 packages.  The package name is in the code.

Marquee Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

public class Marquee implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new MarqueeFrame(new MarqueeModel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Marquee());
    }

}
```

CreateMarqueeActionListener Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

public class CreateMarqueeActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField field;

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public CreateMarqueeActionListener(MarqueeFrame frame, MarqueeModel model,
            JTextField field) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        model.stopDtpRunnable();
        model.resetPixels();

        String s = field.getText().trim();
        if (s.equals("")) {
            frame.repaintMarqueePanel();
            return;
        }

        s = " " + s + "    ";
        model.setTextPixels(model.getDefaultFont().getTextPixels(s));
        frame.repaintMarqueePanel();
    }

}
```

FontSelectionListener Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.controller;

import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeFont;
import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;

public class FontSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public FontSelectionListener(MarqueeModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) event
                .getSource();
        if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int index = selectionModel.getMinSelectionIndex();
            if (index >= 0) {
                MarqueeFont font = model.getDefaultListModel().get(index);
                model.setDefaultFont(font);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

FontGenerator Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FontGenerator {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private Font font;

    private FontHeights fontHeights;

    private Map<Character, MarqueeCharacter> characterMap;

    public FontGenerator(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
        this.characterMap = new HashMap<Character, MarqueeCharacter>();
    }

    public void execute() {
        int width = 50;
        BufferedImage bi = generateCharacterImage(width, "B");
        int[] result1 = getCharacterHeight(bi);
        bi = generateCharacterImage(width, "g");
        int[] result2 = getCharacterHeight(bi);
        fontHeights = new FontHeights(result1[0], result1[1], result2[1]);

        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(fontHeights.getAscender() + ", "
                + fontHeights.getBaseline() + ", "
                + fontHeights.getDescender());

        for (int x = 32; x < 127; x++) {
            char c = (char) x;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(3);
            builder.append('H');
            builder.append(c);
            builder.append('H');

            bi = generateCharacterImage(width, builder.toString());
            int[][] pixels = convertTo2D(bi);
            MarqueeCharacter mc = getCharacterPixels(pixels);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println(builder.toString() + " " +
                        mc.getWidth() + "x" + mc.getHeight());
            }

            characterMap.put(c, mc);
        }

    }

    private BufferedImage generateCharacterImage(int width, String string) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                width, width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(font);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, width);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(string, 0, width / 2);

        return bi;
    }

    private int[] getCharacterHeight(BufferedImage bi) {
        int[][] pixels = convertTo2D(bi);
        int minHeight = bi.getHeight();
        int maxHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
                if (pixels[i][j] < -1) {
                    minHeight = Math.min(i, minHeight);
                    maxHeight = Math.max(i, maxHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        int[] result = new int[2];
        result[0] = minHeight;
        result[1] = maxHeight;
        return result;
    }

    private MarqueeCharacter getCharacterPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        List<Boolean[]> list = new ArrayList<Boolean[]>();
        int startRow = fontHeights.getAscender();
        int endRow = fontHeights.getDescender();
        int height = fontHeights.getCharacterHeight();
        int startColumn = getCharacterColumnStart(pixels);
        int endColumn = getCharacterColumnEnd(pixels);

        for (int i = startColumn; i <= endColumn; i++) {
            Boolean[] characterColumn = new Boolean[height];
            int k = 0;
            for (int j = startRow; j <= endRow; j++) {
                if (pixels[j][i] < -1) characterColumn[k] = true;
                else characterColumn[k] = false;
                k++;
            }
            list.add(characterColumn);
        }

        MarqueeCharacter mc = new MarqueeCharacter(list.size(), height);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Boolean[] characterColumn = list.get(i);
            mc.setColumn(characterColumn);
        }

        return mc;
    }

    private int getCharacterColumnStart(int[][] pixels) {
        int start = fontHeights.getAscender();
        int end = fontHeights.getBaseline();
        int letterEndFlag = 0;
        int column = 1;

        while (letterEndFlag < 1) {
            boolean pixelDetected = false;
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (pixels[i][column] < -1) {
                    pixelDetected = true;
                }
            }

            column++;

            // End of first letter
            if ((letterEndFlag == 0) && !pixelDetected) letterEndFlag = 1;
        }

        return column;
    }

    private int getCharacterColumnEnd(int[][] pixels) {
        int start = fontHeights.getAscender();
        int end = fontHeights.getBaseline();
        int height = fontHeights.getCharacterHeight2();
        int letterEndFlag = 0;
        int column = pixels.length - 1;

        while (letterEndFlag < 4) {
            int pixelCount = 0;
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (pixels[i][column] < -1) {
                    pixelCount++;
                }
            }

            column--;

            // End of first letter
            if (pixelCount >= height) letterEndFlag++;
            // Start of first letter
//          if ((letterEndFlag == 0) && (pixelCount > 0)) letterEndFlag = 1;
        }

        return column;
    }

    private int[][] convertTo2D(BufferedImage image) {
        final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();

        int[][] result = new int[height][width];

        for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel++) {
            result[row][col] = pixels[pixel];
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public MarqueeCharacter getCharacter(Character c) {
        MarqueeCharacter mc = characterMap.get(c);
        return (mc == null) ? characterMap.get('?') : mc;
    }

    public int getCharacterHeight() {
        return fontHeights.getCharacterHeight();
    }
}
```

FontHeights Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

public class FontHeights {

    private final int ascender;
    private final int baseline;
    private final int descender;

    public FontHeights(int ascender, int baseline, int descender) {
        this.ascender = ascender;
        this.baseline = baseline;
        this.descender = descender;
    }

    public int getCharacterHeight() {
        return descender - ascender + 1;
    }

    public int getCharacterHeight2() {
        return baseline - ascender + 1;
    }

    public int getAscender() {
        return ascender;
    }

    public int getBaseline() {
        return baseline;
    }

    public int getDescender() {
        return descender;
    }

}
```

MarqueeCharacter Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

public class MarqueeCharacter {

    private static int columnCount;

    private int height;
    private int width;

    private boolean[][] pixels;

    public MarqueeCharacter(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.pixels = new boolean[width][height];
        columnCount = 0;
    }

    public void setColumn(Boolean[] value) {
        int height = value.length;
        if (this.height != height) {
            String s = "The number of values must equal the column height - "
                    + this.height;
            throw new InvalidParameterException(s);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            pixels[columnCount][i] = value[i];
        }

        columnCount++;
    }

    public boolean[][] getPixels() {
        return pixels;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return (width == columnCount);
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

}
```

MarqueeFont Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class MarqueeFont {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private int fontHeight;

    private Font font;

    public MarqueeFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;

        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds("HgH", frc);
        this.fontHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(font.getFamily() + " " + fontHeight + " pixels");
        }
    }

    public boolean[][] getTextPixels(String s) {
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
        int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
        int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
        int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
        int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.print(s);
            System.out.print(", rWidth = " + rWidth);
            System.out.print(", rHeight = " + rHeight);
            System.out.println(", rX = " + rX + ", rY = " + rY);
        }

        BufferedImage bi = generateCharacterImage(rX, -rY, rWidth, rHeight, s);
        int[][] pixels = convertTo2D(bi);

        if (DEBUG) {
            displayPixels(pixels);
        }

        return createTextPixels(pixels);
    }

    private BufferedImage generateCharacterImage(int x, int y, int width,
            int height, String string) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(font);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(string, x, y);

        return bi;
    }

    private int[][] convertTo2D(BufferedImage image) {
        final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();

        int[][] result = new int[height][width];

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        for (int pixel = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel++) {
            result[row][col] = pixels[pixel];
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void displayPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            String s = String.format("%03d", (i + 1));
            System.out.print(s + ". ");
            for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
                if (pixels[i][j] == -1) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private boolean[][] createTextPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        // The int array pixels is in column, row order.
        // We have to flip the array and produce the output
        // in row, column order.
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(pixels[0].length + "x" + pixels.length);
        }
        boolean[][] textPixels = new boolean[pixels[0].length][pixels.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
                if (pixels[i][j] == -1) {
                    textPixels[j][i] = false;
                } else {
                    textPixels[j][i] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return textPixels;
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

    public int getFontHeight() {
        return fontHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(font.getFamily());
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(getStyleText());
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(font.getSize());
        builder.append(" pixels");

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder getStyleText() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int style = font.getStyle();
        if (style == Font.PLAIN) {
            builder.append("normal");
        } else if (style == Font.BOLD) {
            builder.append("bold");
        } else if (style == Font.ITALIC) {
            builder.append("italic");
        } else if (style == (Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC)) {
            builder.append("bold italic");
        } else {
            builder.append("unknown style");
        }
        return builder;
    }

}
```

MarqueeFontFactory Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class MarqueeFontFactory {

    private DefaultListModel<MarqueeFont> fontList;

    private MarqueeFont defaultFont;

    public MarqueeFontFactory() {
        this.fontList = new DefaultListModel<MarqueeFont>();
        addElements();
    }

    private void addElements() {
        this.defaultFont = new MarqueeFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        fontList.addElement(defaultFont);
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 16)));
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD,
                16)));
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16)));
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Lucida Calligraphy",
                Font.BOLD, 16)));
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Times New Roman",
                Font.BOLD, 16)));
        fontList.addElement(new MarqueeFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 16)));
    }

    public DefaultListModel<MarqueeFont> getFontList() {
        return fontList;
    }

    public void setDefaultFont(MarqueeFont defaultFont) {
        this.defaultFont = defaultFont;
    }

    public MarqueeFont getDefaultFont() {
        return defaultFont;
    }

    public int getCharacterHeight() {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fontList.getSize(); i++) {
            MarqueeFont font = fontList.get(i);
            int height = font.getFontHeight();
            maxHeight = Math.max(height, maxHeight);
        }
        return maxHeight;
    }
}
```

MarqueeModel Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import com.ggl.marquee.runnable.DisplayTextPixelsRunnable;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

public class MarqueeModel {

    private static final int marqueeWidth = 120;

    private boolean[][] marqueePixels;
    private boolean[][] textPixels;

    private DisplayTextPixelsRunnable dtpRunnable;

    private MarqueeFontFactory fonts;

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    public MarqueeModel() {
        this.fonts = new MarqueeFontFactory();
        this.marqueePixels = new boolean[marqueeWidth][getMarqueeHeight()];
    }

    public void setFrame(MarqueeFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public MarqueeFontFactory getFonts() {
        return fonts;
    }

    public DefaultListModel<MarqueeFont> getDefaultListModel() {
        return fonts.getFontList();
    }

    public MarqueeFont getDefaultFont() {
        return fonts.getDefaultFont();
    }

    public void setDefaultFont(MarqueeFont defaultFont) {
        fonts.setDefaultFont(defaultFont);
    }

    public boolean[][] getMarqueePixels() {
        return marqueePixels;
    }

    public boolean getMarqueePixel(int width, int height) {
        return marqueePixels[width][height];
    }

    public int getMarqueeWidth() {
        return marqueeWidth;
    }

    public int getMarqueeHeight() {
        return fonts.getCharacterHeight();
    }

    public boolean[][] getTextPixels() {
        return textPixels;
    }

    public int getTextPixelWidth() {
        return textPixels.length;
    }

    private void startDtpRunnable() {
        dtpRunnable = new DisplayTextPixelsRunnable(frame, this);
        new Thread(dtpRunnable).start();
    }

    public void stopDtpRunnable() {
        if (dtpRunnable != null) {
            dtpRunnable.stopDisplayTextPixelsRunnable();
            dtpRunnable = null;
        }
    }

    public void setTextPixels(boolean[][] textPixels) {
        this.textPixels = textPixels;
        if (textPixels.length < getMarqueeWidth()) {
            this.marqueePixels = copyCharacterPixels(0, textPixels,
                    marqueePixels);
        } else {
            startDtpRunnable();
        }
    }

    public void resetPixels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getMarqueeWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getMarqueeHeight(); j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAllPixels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getMarqueeWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getMarqueeHeight(); j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean[][] copyCharacterPixels(int position,
            boolean[][] characterPixels, boolean[][] textPixels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < characterPixels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < characterPixels[i].length; j++) {
                textPixels[i + position][j] = characterPixels[i][j];
            }
        }

        return textPixels;
    }

    public void copyTextPixels(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < marqueePixels.length; i++) {
            int k = i + position;
            k %= textPixels.length;
            for (int j = 0; j < textPixels[i].length; j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = textPixels[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

DisplayAllPixelsRunnable Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.runnable;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

public class DisplayAllPixelsRunnable implements Runnable {

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public DisplayAllPixelsRunnable(MarqueeFrame frame, MarqueeModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        model.setAllPixels();
        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        model.resetPixels();
        repaint();
    }

    private void repaint() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.repaintMarqueePanel();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

DisplayTextPixelsRunnable Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.runnable;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

public class DisplayTextPixelsRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static int textPixelPosition;

    private volatile boolean running;

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public DisplayTextPixelsRunnable(MarqueeFrame frame, MarqueeModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        textPixelPosition = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.running = true;
        while (running) {
            model.copyTextPixels(textPixelPosition);
            repaint();
            sleep();
            textPixelPosition++;
            textPixelPosition %= model.getTextPixelWidth();
        }
    }

    private void repaint() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.repaintMarqueePanel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopDisplayTextPixelsRunnable() {
        this.running = false;
    }

}
```

ControlPanel Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import com.ggl.marquee.controller.CreateMarqueeActionListener;
import com.ggl.marquee.controller.FontSelectionListener;
import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeFont;
import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;

public class ControlPanel {

    private JButton submitButton;

    private JPanel panel;

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public ControlPanel(MarqueeFrame frame, MarqueeModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel fontPanel = new JPanel();
        fontPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel fontLabel = new JLabel("Fonts");
        fontPanel.add(fontLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JList<MarqueeFont> fontList = new JList<MarqueeFont>(
                model.getDefaultListModel());
        fontList.setSelectedValue(model.getDefaultFont(), true);
        fontList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        fontList.setVisibleRowCount(3);

        ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = fontList.getSelectionModel();
        listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new FontSelectionListener(
                model));

        JScrollPane fontScrollPane = new JScrollPane(fontList);

        fontPanel.add(fontScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.add(fontPanel);

        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel fieldLabel = new JLabel("Marquee Text: ");
        fieldPanel.add(fieldLabel);

        JTextField field = new JTextField(30);
        fieldPanel.add(field);

        panel.add(fieldPanel);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(new CreateMarqueeActionListener(frame,
                model, field));
        buttonPanel.add(submitButton);

        panel.add(buttonPanel);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public JButton getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }

}
```

MarqueeFrame Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.view;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.runnable.DisplayAllPixelsRunnable;

public class MarqueeFrame {

    private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    private DisplayAllPixelsRunnable dapRunnable;

    private JFrame frame;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    private MarqueePanel marqueePanel;

    public MarqueeFrame(MarqueeModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.setFrame(this);
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        // frame.setIconImage(getFrameImage());
        frame.setTitle("Marquee");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        marqueePanel = new MarqueePanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(marqueePanel);
        controlPanel = new ControlPanel(this, model);
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel.getPanel());

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(controlPanel.getSubmitButton());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        dapRunnable = new DisplayAllPixelsRunnable(this, model);
        new Thread(dapRunnable).start();
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void repaintMarqueePanel() {
        marqueePanel.repaint();
    }

}
```

MarqueePanel Class

```
package com.ggl.marquee.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;

public class MarqueePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1677343084333836763L;

    private static final int pixelWidth = 4;
    private static final int gapWidth = 2;
    private static final int totalWidth = pixelWidth + gapWidth;
    private static final int yStart = gapWidth + totalWidth + totalWidth;

    private MarqueeModel model;

    public MarqueePanel(MarqueeModel model) {
        this.model = model;

        int width = model.getMarqueeWidth() * totalWidth + gapWidth;
        int height = model.getMarqueeHeight() * totalWidth + yStart + yStart;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        int x = gapWidth;
        int y = yStart;

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getMarqueeWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < model.getMarqueeHeight(); j++) {
                if (model.getMarqueePixel(i, j)) {
                    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

                g.fillRect(x, y, pixelWidth, pixelWidth);
                y += totalWidth;
            }
            y = yStart;
            x += totalWidth;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: An answer can only be 30,000 characters.  I ran out of room.  Here's a link to an explanation of the code.  https://web.archive.org/web/20160415020706/http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=681

Comment: Thanks a lot Gilbert for the effort, but on my System this stutters even worse than my try. I will test it next week on Windows. Maybe in the end it is really just a problem with Java and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I did a few changes upon the same example ([Marquee](https://web.archive.org/web/20160415020706/http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=681)) posted by @Gilbert Le Blanc.

First of all, in the Marquee example the Thread.sleep() method was being used instead of a more modern approach with a TimerTask. I cannot stress enough about how much difference there is between Thread.sleep() and TimerTask.

> Thread.sleep() is inaccurate. How inaccurate depends on the underlying operating system and its timers and schedulers. I've experienced that garbage collection going on in parallel can lead to excessive sleep.
>   Source: [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736681/how-accurate-is-thread-sleep)

This led to an important problem

> The painting function is called **inconsistently** instead of the expected fixed time for 30fps which is roughly 40ms, this generates some of the shuttering problem.
>   Source: me

which is solved partially by the TimerTask approach

> On at least one major operating system (Windows), blocking on a timer has a much better precision and reliability than sleeping.
>   Source: [GameDev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/631130-timer-vs-threadsleep/)

I have noticed a huge improvement when i rewrote the same example but using timerTask and it's surely more fluid than using the example you provided (2D Swing);

I compared it as following, the speed of the Marquee example is more or less the same speed of your 2d swing test put at 10, so try running your test with `int speed = 10;` and the one provided above and see if shutter more or less.

Alternatively, you can try to run the native Marquee Example and the new one with TimerTask and you should see an important major difference.

I think implementing a buffer strategy with this one is the way to go for achieving a truly fluid scroll experience...otherwise there is always OpenGL

The classes i changed:

**DisplayTextPixelsRunnable** is now **DisplayTextPixelsTimerTask**

```
package com.ggl.marquee.runnable;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.marquee.model.MarqueeModel;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DisplayTextPixelsTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private static int textPixelPosition;

    private final MarqueeFrame frame;

    private final MarqueeModel model;

    public DisplayTextPixelsTimerTask(MarqueeFrame frame, MarqueeModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        textPixelPosition = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        model.copyTextPixels(textPixelPosition);
        repaint();
        textPixelPosition++;
        textPixelPosition %= model.getTextPixelWidth();
    }

    private void repaint() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(frame::repaintMarqueePanel);
    }

}
```

**MarqueeModel**

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import com.ggl.marquee.runnable.DisplayTextPixelsTimerTask;
import com.ggl.marquee.view.MarqueeFrame;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MarqueeModel {

    private static final int marqueeWidth = 120;

    private static final long FPS_TARGET = 30;
    private static final long DELAY_TIME = (long) (1000.0d / FPS_TARGET);

    private boolean[][] marqueePixels;
    private boolean[][] textPixels;

    private TimerTask dtpRunnable;

    private MarqueeFontFactory fonts;

    private MarqueeFrame frame;

    public MarqueeModel() {
        this.fonts = new MarqueeFontFactory();
        this.marqueePixels = new boolean[marqueeWidth][getMarqueeHeight()];
    }

    public void setFrame(MarqueeFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public MarqueeFontFactory getFonts() {
        return fonts;
    }

    public DefaultListModel<MarqueeFont> getDefaultListModel() {
        return fonts.getFontList();
    }

    public MarqueeFont getDefaultFont() {
        return fonts.getDefaultFont();
    }

    public void setDefaultFont(MarqueeFont defaultFont) {
        fonts.setDefaultFont(defaultFont);
    }

    public boolean[][] getMarqueePixels() {
        return marqueePixels;
    }

    public boolean getMarqueePixel(int width, int height) {
        return marqueePixels[width][height];
    }

    public int getMarqueeWidth() {
        return marqueeWidth;
    }

    public int getMarqueeHeight() {
        return fonts.getCharacterHeight();
    }

    public boolean[][] getTextPixels() {
        return textPixels;
    }

    public int getTextPixelWidth() {
        return textPixels.length;
    }

    private void startDtpRunnable() {
        dtpRunnable = new DisplayTextPixelsTimerTask(frame, this);
        //running timer task as daemon thread
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(dtpRunnable, 0, DELAY_TIME);
    }

    public void stopDtpRunnable() {
        if (dtpRunnable != null) {
            dtpRunnable.cancel();
            dtpRunnable = null;
        }
    }

    public void setTextPixels(boolean[][] textPixels) {
        this.textPixels = textPixels;
        if (textPixels.length < getMarqueeWidth()) {
            this.marqueePixels = copyCharacterPixels(0, textPixels,
                    marqueePixels);
        } else {
            startDtpRunnable();
        }
    }

    public void resetPixels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getMarqueeWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getMarqueeHeight(); j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setAllPixels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getMarqueeWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getMarqueeHeight(); j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean[][] copyCharacterPixels(int position,
                                           boolean[][] characterPixels, boolean[][] textPixels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < characterPixels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < characterPixels[i].length; j++) {
                textPixels[i + position][j] = characterPixels[i][j];
            }
        }

        return textPixels;
    }

    public void copyTextPixels(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < marqueePixels.length; i++) {
            int k = i + position;
            k %= textPixels.length;
            for (int j = 0; j < textPixels[i].length; j++) {
                marqueePixels[i][j] = textPixels[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I don't think it's possible to do more than that using only Java.
To be honest, the Marquee example is the smoothest i saw.