# Java equivalent to (p5.js) p5.Font.textToPoints() function

Tags: java, text, fonts, points

Is there a way in java to get the vertices of a font so they can be displayed as particles in java?
like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a way.  It's not trivial.  I wrote this class as part of a marquee GUI.

Pay particular attention to the `getTextPixels` method.

```
package com.ggl.marquee.model;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class MarqueeFont {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private int fontHeight;

    private Font font;

    public MarqueeFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;

        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds("HgH", frc);
        this.fontHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(font.getFamily() + " " + fontHeight + " pixels");
        }
    }

    public boolean[][] getTextPixels(String s) {
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
        int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
        int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
        int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
        int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.print(s);
            System.out.print(", rWidth = " + rWidth);
            System.out.print(", rHeight = " + rHeight);
            System.out.println(", rX = " + rX + ", rY = " + rY);
        }

        BufferedImage bi = generateCharacterImage(rX, -rY, rWidth, rHeight, s);
        int[][] pixels = convertTo2D(bi);

        if (DEBUG) {
            displayPixels(pixels);
        }

        return createTextPixels(pixels);
    }

    private BufferedImage generateCharacterImage(int x, int y, int width,
            int height, String string) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(font);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(string, x, y);

        return bi;
    }

    private int[][] convertTo2D(BufferedImage image) {
        final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();

        int[][] result = new int[height][width];

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        for (int pixel = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel++) {
            result[row][col] = pixels[pixel];
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void displayPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            String s = String.format("%03d", (i + 1));
            System.out.print(s + ". ");
            for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
                if (pixels[i][j] == -1) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private boolean[][] createTextPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        // The int array pixels is in column, row order.
        // We have to flip the array and produce the output
        // in row, column order.
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(pixels[0].length + "x" + pixels.length);
        }
        boolean[][] textPixels = new boolean[pixels[0].length][pixels.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
                if (pixels[i][j] == -1) {
                    textPixels[j][i] = false;
                } else {
                    textPixels[j][i] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return textPixels;
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

    public int getFontHeight() {
        return fontHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(font.getFamily());
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(getStyleText());
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(font.getSize());
        builder.append(" pixels");

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder getStyleText() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int style = font.getStyle();
        if (style == Font.PLAIN) {
            builder.append("normal");
        } else if (style == Font.BOLD) {
            builder.append("bold");
        } else if (style == Font.ITALIC) {
            builder.append("italic");
        } else if (style == (Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC)) {
            builder.append("bold italic");
        } else {
            builder.append("unknown style");
        }
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Comment: how would this class be utilized?

Comment: The answer that shows the GUI and the rest of the classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005947/marquee-ticker-text-scroll-with-java2d-or-javafx-stutters/62064178#62064178